# Timeout when sending email via SmtpClient

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I'm trying to send a very simple email via the SmtpClient class.  I've been looking at this for hours and I've been following examples from StackOverflow and MSDN, but for some reason I get nothing but timeouts.

I've changed the hostnames and passwords, but I've added the code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Int32 port = 465;
    String host = "host.co.uk";

    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("test@email.co.uk");
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("paul@email.co.uk");

    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);

    msg.Body = "Test Body";
    msg.Subject = "Test Subject";

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Host = host;
    client.Port = port;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@email.co.uk", "password");
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    client.Send(msg);
}
```

As you can see, this is a console application that tries to send the email and then exits.  I took it out of the main project so I could eliminate any other possible causes (apart from the actual email code).

It throws a `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException` with the value

```
The operation has timed out.
```

What I think is causing the problem is the credentials, because if you look at the values in 'client' it shows the Credentials property as null, despite being set in the code.

I have to admit to being stumped.  Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Who is your real email provider? Is it an internally hosted server? Google? AOL? Based on that there might be additional steps you need to do in order to establish a connection to the smtp server.

Comment: Comment out the line that set the UseDefaultCredentials to false

Comment: Sometimes your internet service provider blocks email ports.  Not sure if this is the case here, but I would try a few different ports if you haven't already.

Comment: do you mean hosts.co.uk? Most cases the host is written like smtp.host.co.uk. Have you tried port 587?

Comment: @DavidLee I can't change the port on the server as it's provided by a hosting service.

Comment: @Igor Xilo.net is hosting it.

Comment: @mike I'm using the port that is specified by the hosting provider.  Also the provider has specifically stated that it's in that format, I've also tried putting smtp. in front but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Steve Commenting out the line that sets UseDefaultCredentials to false solved the issue of the Credentials property being null, but it still timed out.

Comment: Take note port 465 is SSL.

Comment: @mike I would rather send with SSL on if I can.  But if I turn it to port 25 and add

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate,
             X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    { return true; };

I can get it to work (Xilo uses some generic SSL cert for all email, Outlook doesn't like it either).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but it may help someone...

I had this time out issue occur with a particular SMTP server, using code that had worked for years with numerous other providers (including gmail).

It turns out that [Microsoft themselves don't recommend using the SmtpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-7.0) as it doesn't support many modern protocols. They recommend [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) (NuGet: `Install-Package MailKit`)as an alternative. MailKit is very similar, code-wise, so easy to switch to. It immediately solved my problem.

[image: Image from Microsoft's official documentation describing why they do not recommend using their own SmtpClient class]